# How to test 7 customer transaction per second?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, stress-testing

I am using jmeter for my performance test.  The website needs to perform `7 customer transaction per second with the average TPS of 22.19 and maximum TPS of 25.01.`  So I have defined my test plan with 7 threads to run with 3 loops and asserted the response with 200 and 204. I also `asserted the response with duration response for 2 second since it is needed.`

but I am pretty confused how to assert this `average TPS and maximum TPS` ?. I am also not sure how to test `7 customer transaction per second`. ? Thanks for you help.

Comment: What is your "T"in TPS.  Is it an individual request/Response pair (a hit), a page, a completion of a multi-step business process (a sales order completion).   Understanding your "T" will help to understand the setup to hit your rate level

Comment: It is an individual request/response (a hit) a page.

Comment: A page can be made up of hundreds of hits (individual requests).  So, please clarify, is this an individual request or is it a page with all of its components?

Comment: The term TPS i am referring is number of actions performed . so it is an individual request.

Comment: Then simply loading one page per second and all of its components should satisfy your seven TPS.  Why?  Because modern browsers download on six download threads in parallel.  Unless all of your page components are huge and your network catastrophically slow, at least one of your page components is going to complete in under a second, allowing a seventh thread to start.   Validate the request TPS by pulling the HTTP logs, count requests grouped by second

Answer (score 1):

1. Put all requests which belong to a `customer transaction` under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-Transaction-controller-behavior/) and rename it to `customer-transaction`
2. Download and [install](https://gettaurus.org/install/Installation/) Taurus tool
3. Create [Taurus YAML config](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) file for running your JMeter test looking like:

   ```
   execution:
     - scenario: simple

   scenarios:
     simple:
       script: test.jmx
   reporting:
     - module: passfail
       criteria:
         - hits for customer-transaction>7 for 1s, stop as failed
   ```
4. That's it, if you will be receiving less than 7 hits per second the test will be automatically stopped as failed and have non-zero [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status)